# How can I make a Like button (like youtubes) using only embed code

Tags: html, embed

I recently tried making a youtube like button but ran into a stopping point.

I tried searching on google and found no results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like https://fonts.google.com/icons
For example, you can use the following code to make a like button:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />

<span class="material-symbols-outlined">
    thumb_up
</span>
```